# Trying to add an object to an Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

I am doing an app but I have a problem: I'm trying to add values to an Array but I cannot do it, the value that return my function called create_division_and_grades is an empty array []

```
async function create_division_and_grades(grades /*Array */, divisions /*Object */, school /*Object*/) {

    var new_grades = []

    await grades.forEach(async grade => {

        const new_grade = new Grade({
            number: grade,
            school,
        })

        await divisions[`${grade}`].forEach(async division => {
            const new_division = new Division({
                character: division,
                school,
                grade: new_grade,
            })
            const saved_division = await new_division.save()
            new_grade.divisions.push(saved_division)

        })


        const saved_grade = await new_grade.save()


        new_grades.push(saved_grade)

    })

    return new_grades
```

And this is the way I use the function:

```
const grades_primary = await create_division_and_grades(info.grades_primary, info.divisions_primary, new_school)
```

Where **info.grades_primary** is:
`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` 
and **info.divisions_primary** is:
`{ "1" : ["A", "B"], "2":["A", "B"], "3":["A", "B"], "4":["A", "B"], "5":["A", "B"], "6":["A", "B"] }`

Comment: The callback to `.forEach()` is expected to be synchronous, so you can't make it `async` and expect it to behave correctly, instead, use a normal for-loop

Comment: You probably want to `await` [Promise.all(promises)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

Answer (score 0):

In your case you better use Array.map() to achieve your target

```
async function create_division_and_grades(grades /*Array */, divisions /*Object */, school /*Object*/) {
    const createdGrades = await Promise.all(
        grades.map(async grade => {
            const gradeToSave = new Grade({
                number: grade,
                school
            });

            const gradeDivisionList = divisions[`${grade}`];

            gradeToSave.divisions = await Promise.all(
                gradeDivisionList.map(division => {
                    const divisionToSave = new Division({
                        character: division,
                        school,
                        grade: gradeToSave
                    });

                    return divisionToSave.save();
                })
            );

            return gradeToSave.save();
        })
    );

    return createdGrades;
}
```

Or if you want to save your entities sequentially, you can use another approach

```
export const runSequentially = (array, sequenceCallback) =>
    array.reduce(
        (promise, element) =>
            promise.then(promiseResult =>
                sequenceCallback(element).then(callbackResult => [...promiseResult, callbackResult])
            ),
        Promise.resolve([])

async function create_division_and_grades(grades /*Array */, divisions /*Object */, school /*Object*/) {
    const createdGrades = await runSequentially(grades, async grade => {
        const gradeToSave = new Grade({
            number: grade,
            school
        });

        const gradeDivisionList = divisions[`${grade}`];

        gradeToSave.divisions = await runSequentially(gradeDivisionList, division => {
            const divisionToSave = new Division({
                character: division,
                school,
                grade: gradeToSave
            });

            return divisionToSave.save();
        });

        return gradeToSave.save();
    });

    return createdGrades;
}
```